# XRDP Crashes when Sublime is run

Tags: xrdp

I can connect to my Ubuntu machine from a windows machine using windows remote desktop.

But I can't run programs like sublime as it crashes the `xrdp`. I can open terminals and simple text editor programs on Ubuntu without crashing the `xrdp`.

If I run `glxgears` while on the `xrdp` session, it prints the error :

```
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

While I can ssh to Ubuntu and run `glxgears` just fine.

What could be the issue here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All fixed after installing the latest version of xrdp